# AngularJS directive doesn't update scope value even with apply

Tags: angularjs

I'm usin a directive to show a div on the screen only when the screen size is smaller than 600px. The problem is, the scope value isn't being updated, even using `$apply()` inside the directive.

This is the code:

```
function showBlock($window,$timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.isBlock = false;
            checkScreen();

            function checkScreen() {
                var wid = $window.innerWidth;
                if (wid <= 600) {
                    if(!scope.isBlock) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            scope.isBlock = true;
                            scope.$apply();
                        }, 100);
                    };

                } else if (wid > 600) {
                    if(scope.isBlock) {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            scope.isBlock = false;
                            scope.$apply();
                        }, 100);
                    };
                };
            };
            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
                checkScreen();
            }); 
        }
    };
}
```

html:

```
<div ng-if="isBlock" show-block>
    //..conent to show
</div>
<div ng-if="!isBlock" show-block>
    //..other conent to show
</div>
```

Note: If I don't use $timeout I'll get the error

> $digest already in progress

I used console logs inside to check if it's updating the value, and inside the directive everything works fine. But the changes doesn't go to the view. The block doesn't show.

Comment: if you want to view your data different depending on your window size you should use css, like `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)`

Comment: I know about this, but this is going to be used for other purpouses, so even with a basic example I'll expand it later. Also, ng-if doesn't render the html, which in this case, is pretty extensive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `do rule` in such cases to get the advantage of [**Prototypal Inheritance of AngularJS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/2435473).

Basically you need to create a object, that will will have various property. Like in your case you could have `$scope.model = {}` and then place `isBlock` property inside it. So that when you are inside your directive, you will get access to parent scope. The reason behind it is, you are having `scope: true`, which says that the which has been created in directive is prototypically inherited from parent scope. That means all the reference type objects are available in your child scope.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-if="model.isBlock" show-block>
    //..conent to show
</div>
<div ng-if="!model.isBlock" show-block>
    //..other conent to show
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
   //your controller code here

   //here you can have object defined here so that it can have properties in it
   //and child scope will get access to it.
   $scope.model = {}; //this is must to use dot rule,
   //instead of toggle property here you could do it from directive too
   $scope.isBlock = false; //just for demonstration purpose

});
```

and then inside your directive you should use `scope.model.isBlock` instead of `scope.isBlock`

**Update**

As you are using `controllerAs` pattern inside your code, you need to use `scope.ag.model.isBlock`. which will provide you an access to get that scope variable value inside your directive.

Basically you can get the parent controller value(used `controllerAs` pattern) make available controller value inside the child one. You can find object with your controller alias inside the `$scope`. Like here you have created `ag` as controller alias, so you need to do `scope.ag.model` to get the `model` value inside directive link function.

**NOTE**

You don't need to use `$apply` with `$timeout`, which may throw an error `$apply in progress`, so $timeout will run digest for you, you don't need to worry about to run digest.

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/B0NywQ6EHgzrJRdFeIyj?p=preview)

Comment: isn't it possible to control everything from the directive?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade in your case no..you have to have atleast `$scope.model = {};` define on your controller..

Comment: Even if not using scope:true ? Because the directive functionality is to control only this.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be `$scope.model = { isBlock:false }` ? Instead of 2 $scope values?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade if you removed `scope: true` you could wouldn't work..because you had `ng-if` directive on your `DOM`, if you look at the `ngIf` directive API it use `scope: true` option..you could fix that issue just by switch it to `ng-show`..but I'd hardly recommend you do follow above mention approach.

Comment: Could you provide a working example? I tried to follow your steps, but I got his error: `isBlock of undefined`. By the way, I'm using `controllerAs` syntax, so instead of $scope in my controller I'm using `ag.model = {}`

Comment: @CelsomTrindade could yo ugive me plunkr with whatever you have tried till?

Comment: Ok, I'll do it and send to you

Comment: @CelsomTrindade sure thing

Comment: Check this out: https://plnkr.co/edit/aH1r0y8HJ8HrNmwMk3kl?p=preview In the console you can see the error I was talking about.

Comment: Understood! But do you see how it doesn't update when resizing the window? It stick to the first value, whether it's true or false, it doesn't change.

Comment: I've made it work, but had to use $timeout and $apply, is this the best way? https://plnkr.co/edit/aH1r0y8HJ8HrNmwMk3kl?p=preview

Comment: @CelsomTrindade apology that I don't get to time to look at it again.. https://plnkr.co/edit/aH1r0y8HJ8HrNmwMk3kl?p=preview here is updated code basically you don't need to use `$apply` with `$timeout`

Comment: Sorry, but, It's the same plunker I sent you, still have apply and timeout

Comment: Oh, ok. I understood! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help you.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the show-block directive wouldn't be fired if ng-if="isBlock" is never true, so it would never register the resize event.

Comment: I noticed this after i made the question. Then i inserted other div with the opposite value (see edited question) but the problem still persists.. When using log, I can se the resize event at all times.

Comment: The scope: true means the isBlock before the directive is in a different scope than the one you are setting/changing in the directive. Try removing that.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience linear code never works well with dynamic DOM properties such as window sizing. With code that is looking for screens size you need to put that in some sort of event / DOM observer e.g. in angular I'd use a $watch to observe the the dimensions. So to fix this you need to place you code in a $watch e.g below. I have not tested this code, just directional. You can watch $window.innerWidth or you can watch $element e.g. body depending on your objective. I say this as screens will be all over the place but if you control a DOM element, such as, body you have better control. also I've not use $timeout for brevity sake.

```
// watch window width
showBlock.$inject = ['$window'];
function bodyOverflow($window) {
    var isBlock = false;
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch($window.innerWidth, function (newWidth, oldWidth) {
                if (newWidth !== oldWidth) {
                    return isBlock = newWidth <= 600;
                }
            })
        }
    };
}

// OR watch element width
showBlock.$inject = [];
function bodyOverflow() {
    var isBlock = false;
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch($element, function (new, old) {
                if (newWidth) {
                    return isBlock = newWidth[0].offsetWidth <= 600;
                }
            })
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: though it syntactical mistake, watch `$element` why?

Comment: good catch,  didn't catch that as I took it the code from some of my element  body text overflow code where I have a controller where I inject $element

Comment: Understood the concept, but 2 questions: -How to pass the value to the view? Still not able to do this. -I've read some articles saying using $watch isn't a proper best practice for ng, and can take a hit on the performance. The project I'm working on is kind of complex, so I'm trying to save everywhere it's possible.